# Android Studio is stuck on Downloading on Mac OS

Tags: windows, macos, android-studio

I switched to MAC from windows and my experience with android studio on MAC sucks. I wonder if I am missing something or the bug is with new version of android 3.0.1.

Android studio doesn't even gradle some apps which work perfectly on my windows machine. The gradle takes forever and I wasn't successful in running the apps. And one more issue is that Android studio doesn't quit, and I can't shutdown my laptop, it says android studio is open, I tried to quit android studio is stuck. Freezes I don't know my Mac specs are better than windows laptop.

What version of android studio do you use and how do you overcome this problem, do you prefer Mac over windows? or do you think I should switch back. But I invested a lot on this MacBook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured out what was causing the issue, Firewall was stopping android studio from connecting to internet.

Solution is simple, just add android studio to firewall

Go to System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Firewall -> Firewall Options, Click on "+" and add android studio.

[image]